# Owl Carousel com filtro

Tags: php, jquery, owl-carousel

Eu tenho 3 botões:
TODOS - CASAS - APARTAMENTOS.

Ao carregar a página, o carousel deve mostrar todas as imagens.
Mas ao clicar nos botões CASA ou APARTAMENTOS ele deverá filtrar apenas determinas imagens.
Ao clicar em TODOS deve voltar a mostrar todas as imagens.

HTML:
""

```
 <div>
      <div class="container">
          
                <li class="fotos" data-content="1" active-item>
                     <a name="0" href="#" class="umcard" >
                          <button class="btn-slide-imagens">Todos</button>
                     </a>
                </li>

                <li class="fotos" data-content="2">
                     <a name="0" href="#" class="umcard" >
                          <button class="btn-slide-imagens">Casas</button>
                     </a>
                </li>

                <li class="fotos" data-content="3">
                     <a name="0" href="#" class="umcard" >
                          <button class="btn-slide-imagens">Apartamentos</button>
                     </a>
                </li>
                
           </ul>       
      </div>

 </div>

 <div id="owl-imovel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme imovel-space">
      <div class="teste-1">
           <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/slide/img1.png">
      </div>

      <div class="teste-2">
           <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/slide/img2.png">
      </div>

      <div class="teste-3">
           <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/slide/img3.png">
      </div>

      <div class="teste-4">
           <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/slide/img4.png">
      </div>

      <div class="teste-5">
           <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/slide/img5.png">
      </div>
      <div class="teste-6">
           <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/slide/img6.png">
      </div>
 </div>
```

""

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.product-carousel').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            slidesToShow: 4
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '10px',
            slidesToShow: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    });
});

var filtered = false;

$('.product-button').on('click', function(){
    var filtername = $(this).parent('li').attr('id');
    var currentclass = $(this).attr('class');
  if (filtered === false) {
    $('.product-carousel').slick('slickUnfilter');
    $('.product-carousel').slick('slickFilter','.filter-' + filtername);

   $('.product-button').attr('class', 'btn btn-xs btn-default product-button');
    $(this).attr('class', 'btn btn-xs btn-primary product-button');
  } else {
    $('.product-carousel').slick('slickUnfilter');
    $('.product-carousel').slick('slickFilter', '.filter-' + filtername);
    $('.product-carousel').slickGoTo(0);
    $('.product-button').attr('class', 'btn btn-xs btn-default product-button');
    $(this).attr('class', 'btn btn-xs btn-primary product-button');
    filtered = false;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
    background: black;
}
.vendors {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.product-carousel {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 4em auto;
}

.product-carousel .item {   
    background: green;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 5px;  
    height:440px;
}

.product-carousel .item img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.vendors li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.product-selector {
    width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="product-carousel">
        <div class="item filter-real">
          <img class="product-selector" src="https://agrilifecdn3.tamu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/TexasLandPic.jpg"  />  
      </div>
       <div class="item filter-real">
          <img class="product-selector" src="http://www.fs.fed.us/land/staff/images/uinta.jpg" />               </div>
  
   
   
                <div class="item filter-plan">
                    <img class="product-selector" src="http://www.conceptdraw.com/solution-park/resource/images/solutions/building-plans/BUILDING-PLANS-Floor-Plans-Flat-plan-Sample43.png" /></div>
                <div class="item filter-plan">
                    <img class="product-selector" src="http://img.friv5games.com/2016/02/24/luxury-real-estate-floor-plans-l-9d69606de0081530.jpg" />
      </div>
 
 
                <div class="item filter-aerial">
                    <img class="product-selector" src="http://saveeno.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/aerial_real_estate_st_louis1.jpg" />
      </div>
                <div class="item filter-aerial">
                    <img class="product-selector" src="http://www.skycamusa.com/aerial_photography_gallery/aerial_photos_of_my%20home.jpg" /></div>
      
            </div>
            <div class="vendors-wrapper">
                <ul class="vendors">
                  <li id="real"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary product-button">TODOS</button></li>
                  <li id="plan"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary product-button">CASAS</button></li>
                  <li id="aerial"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary product-button">APARTAMENTO</button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>          
        </div>
</div>
```

Caso dê algum erro de `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` basta adicionar o seguinte:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Considere adicionar mais informações à sua resposta, como o porquê do erro citado acontecer e por quê adicionar o último bloco de código o corrige. Links para documentações também são bem-vindos.